# valuation of a composition of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $K$ be a field, $P$ be a irreducible polynomial of $K[X]$, $v_P$ be the valuation of $K[X]$ associated to $P$. Does one have $v_P(Q\circ R)=v_p(Q)\times v_P(R)$ for two polynomials $Q,R$ of $K[X]$.
Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $P=X+1, Q=X, R=X+1$. Clearly $v_P(Q\circ R)=1\not= v_P(Q) \times v_P(R) =0$.